# Login form not working! python

Tags: python, python-2.7, authentication

in this login form only working for same 'username' and 'password'! i want it work for if any 'username' get match to str from 'password' list then also it has to work.. help..!!!

```
        self.usernamelist = ['aniruddh','firoz','ashish']
        self.passwordlist = ['aniruddh','firoz','ashish']

        self.connect(self.okbutton, SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.loginfunction)


    def loginfunction(self):
        usernamestatus = False
        usernameindex =  -1
        passwordstatus = False
        passwordindex =  -1
        for currentusername in range(len(self.usernamelist)):
            if self.passwordlist[currentusername] == self.username.text():
                usernamestatus = True
                usernameindex = self.usernamelist.index(self.passwordlist[currentusername])

        for currentpassword in range(len(self.passwordlist)):
            if self.usernamelist[currentpassword] == self.password.text():
                passwordstatus = True
                passwordindex = self.passwordlist.index(self.usernamelist[currentpassword])

        if usernamestatus == True and passwordstatus ==True and usernameindex: #== passwordindex:
            self.hide()
            w2 = chooseoption.Form1(self)
            w2.show()


        else:

                        self.msgBox = QMessageBox()
                        self.msgBox.setWindowTitle("Alert!")
                        self.msgBox.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('abcd.ico'))
                        self.msgBox.setText("Unauthorised User!!!")
            self.msgBox.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you are checking the password, you are checking if the password is in the usernamelist! What you need to do is:
1- check if the username exists in the list.
2- check if the password is valid for that username, in your case password on index [i] in passwordlist is valid for username on the same index in usernamelist.

So the login function could be like:

```
def loginfunction(self):
    usernameindex =  -1
    passwordindex =  -1
    username = self.username.text()
    password = self.password.text()
    if username in self.usernamelist: # 1- check: if the username is in the list
        usernameindex = self.usernamelist.index(username) # then: get the index of the username
        if password == self.passwordlist[usernameindex]: # 2- check: if password is equal to the password in passwordlist on the same index of the username
            self.hide()
            w2 = chooseoption.Form1(self)
            w2.show()
        else: # if the password is not correct
            self.msgBox = QMessageBox()
            self.msgBox.setWindowTitle("Alert!")
            self.msgBox.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('abcd.ico'))
            self.msgBox.setText("Incorrect password!!!")

    else: # the username is not in the list
        self.msgBox = QMessageBox()
        self.msgBox.setWindowTitle("Alert!")
        self.msgBox.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('abcd.ico'))
        self.msgBox.setText("Unauthorised User!!!")
```